# how to get the session variable in the view in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Thanks for your valuable suggestions

i have created a login system where i want to store the id's of users in session variables

this is my controller for login system

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class successController extends Controller
{

public function successAction(Request $request)
    {

       --some code for form--
       $repository = $em->getRepository('RepairStoreBundle:users');
        $query = $repository->auth($name,$password);
      $error="sorry invalid username or password";   
           if($query== false)
            {
                return $this->render('RepairLoginBundle:login:login.html.php', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),'error'=>$error,)); 
                }
        else
        {
            $role=$query[0]['role'];
            $id=$query[0]['id'];
            if($role == 1)
            {
                $session = new Session();
                $session->start();
                $session->set('id',$id);
                $result=$repository->display();
            return $this->render('RepairLoginBundle:login:success.html.php',array('result'=>$result,));
            }
            else
            {
             $session = new Session();
             $session->start();
             $session->set('id',$id);
            $res= $repository->edit($id);
        return $this->render('RepairLoginBundle:login:user.html.php',array('res'=>$res));

            }    
        }

    }

}
```

when admin logins with role=1 it will render to success.html.php

in this view how can i get the session variable which  i have set in the controller.
i have used $session->get('id'); 
it is giving me server error please help with this

Answer (score 10):

Upfront Authentication should better be done with the Security Component in Symfony2.
Read more about it in [The Book - Security](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html). You should probably also take a look at [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

Accessing the session from a PHP template in symfony2:

```
echo $app->getSession()->get('whatever');
```

**Session Handling**

There is an article in the official documentation:
[Components/HttpFoundation - Session Data Management](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-data-management)

The API documentation for the Session Component can be found here:
http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html

In the symfony2 standard-edition you can get the session from within a controller with:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

As you already have the request as an argument in successAction you could access the session with:

```
$session = $request->getSession();
```

Set a value with ( $value needs to be serializable ):

```
$session->set('key',$value);
```

Get a value with:

```
$session->get('key');
```

Saving (and closing) the session can be done with:

```
$session->save();
```

You should also loook at the SessionBag class.
you create a SessionBag and register it with the session. see:

[Symfony API](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#registerBag%28%29)

In the registered SessionBag - which implements [AttributeBagInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Attribute/AttributeBagInterface.html) - you can get and set your key/value's as desired.

**TIP:** If you want to get the current User and you have a container aware controller ( container injected )

you can use:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

if you are extending Symfony's Controller class in the standard-edition - the shorter way is:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

or even shorter (Symfony > 2.1.x):

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Alternative ( If your controller is not container aware ):

Define the controller as a service and inject @security.context:

**YAML:**

```
# src/Vendor/YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml 

services:
    my.controller.service:
        class: Vendor\YourBundle\Controller\successController
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
```

**Vendor\YourBundle\Controller\successController:**

```
protected $securityContext;

public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
{
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
}
```

then in your action:

```
$user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
```

**Note:**: you have to use the service in your routing aswell if you choose the controller-as-service variant. example routing.yml :

```
[...]
route_name:
    pattern:  /success
    defaults: { _controller: my.controller.service:successAction }
    [...]
[...]
```

**Note**... you can also inject the session with **"@session"**

```
 # src/Vendor/YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml 
        [...]
        arguments: ["@security.context","@session"]
```

**Note** injecting the whole container is resource-heavy. advanced developers inject their needed services one-by-one and not the whole container.

**Tip:** Normally Controller classes are written with a capital first letter - example: *S*uccessController

**General TIP:** You have unnecessary dublicate code in your example:

```
       // 'if' and 'else' execute the same stuff here
       // result: dublicate code = more code = harder to read

       if($role == 1)
        {
            $session = new Session();
            $session->start();
            [...]
        }
        else
        {
            $session = new Session();
            $session->start();
            [...]
        }
```

should better be ...

```
        // better: put this stuff before the if/else statement 

        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        if($role == 1)
        {
            [...]
        }
        else
        {
            [...]
        }
```

Comment: ya thankyou i got to know by this how to create a session and get it in the view but in the view if the session variable is not set i need to redirect to another view i.e login page.but iam not getting how to call another view from one view we have incude,extends in symfony2 but this will not be useful here

Comment: sorry i think we need to call to the controller from there again to view sorry for stupid question

Comment: @bhari you could 1) change the used template in the controller based on the session content or 2) change it with an if statement and include/extends in your template. Normally with twig templates i use something like {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} ... {% endif %} to output different menus for different user groups for example. If your question has been answered please accept my answer :-)

Comment: sorry i didn't get you nifr in the view i get the the session variable  in the way which you have said                       $var=$app->getSession()->get('id');
if(!isset($var))
{
here i need to do send to controller or view if he is not admin i.e if he didn't use login and directly typing route in the url he should not access that page
}

Comment: I dont really know what you are doing here ... symfony has a role authentication system ... you can add roles to users i.e. ROLE_ADMIN and have a firewall configuration which prevents users from gaining access to /admin/* for example if they dont have this role. Your question was "How to get the session in a template" .. and i more than clearly answered youre question .. so please accept my answer. If you have other questions just phrase a new one.

Comment: ya i understand your answer sorry if i ask any stupid question